# Google Firestore: Filter documents where sub-key is between given value

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a browser game and I have a collection in firestore that looks like this:

```
{
    title: "doc 1",
    requirements: {
        level: {
            min: 2,
            max: 3
        }
    }
},
{
    title: "doc 2",
    requirements: {
        level: {
            min: 6,
            max: 8
        }
    }
},
{
    title: "doc 3",
    requirements: {
        level: {
            min: 8,
            max: 9
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to query for all documents, that match a given level like when I have a level of 8 I only want to fetch the documents "doc 2" and "doc 3" because the level requirements match?

I tried with something like

```
ref.where("requirements.level.min", "<=", level);
ref.where("requirements.level.max", ">=", level);
```

I also tried to change the structure in my documents to this:

```
{
    title: "doc 1",
    requirements: {
        level: [2, 3]
    }
},
{
    title: "doc 2",
    requirements: {
        level: [6, 7, 8]
    }
}
```

and filter it like this

```
ref.where("requirements.level", "array-contains", level)
```

But firestore always returns me all documents.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Will it be helpful if I'll provide you an answer that implies some changes in your database structure?

Comment: I am at the beginning of the development phase so I am thankful about every suggestion!

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that. You siad you have used `ref.where("requirements.level", "array-contains", level)` why do you say it always returns me all documents because is shouln't.

Comment: Yeah that's the big question :D

Comment: I tried it with both ways but firebase returns me every document in the collection and I don't know why.

Comment: In this case, I recommend you post another question with only this issue. You should add your real database structure and the entire code that have used.

Comment: Please check my answer and post more code - array-contains should not return all docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array contains seems to be correct choice here.
I've checked your example - [recreated quite similar structure in my firestore](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ke944mdv0bs00g9/Screenshot%202018-11-22%2017.30.02.png?dl=0)  (other doc has same structure but levels from 5 to 7) and run these queries:

```
const docs = firebase.firestore().collection('docs');
docs.where('requirements.levels','array-contains',2).get().then((snap) => {
    console.log(snap.docs.length); //<- outputs 1, correct
  });
docs.where('requirements.levels','array-contains',4).get().then((snap) => {
    console.log(snap.docs.length); //<- outputs 0, correct
  });
docs.where('requirements.levels','array-contains',5).get().then((snap) => {
    console.log(snap.docs.length); //<- outputs 1, correct
  });
```

Comment: I rewrote this part in my application and recreated the requirements objects in the database. Now it works. I don't know what I did wrong in first place but now it works. Your answer is the closest to the working code, so you get the bounty. Thank you for your help!